# Android receiving push notification from Firebase Cloud Messaging only network state changes

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) from Google to push notifications to IOS and Android.
IOS works fine. All notifications are delivered immediately even when my app is not running.
But Android it happens only a network state change occurs. For instance when switching from LTE / 4G to plane mode and switching back again. In that case the notification is delivered correctly. 
Searching I found something about heart beating. Tried that but no sugar.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.c"));
sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.GTALK_HEARTBEAT"));
sendBroadcast(new Intent("com.google.android.intent.action.MCS_HEARTBEAT"));
```

I have no clue to a next step. And it seems I've dug every page Google offers.

Comment: Could be your phone. Some phone models (including but not limited to Xiaomi or Huawei) have a pretty agressive 'power saving mode' things that will delay incoming notifications for whatever reasons.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think so. Whatsapp, Twitter and others behave different.

Comment: On a second thought... I'll try other phone / brand.

Comment: This looks like a problem with your network infrastructure (if the problem is on wifi) or with the mobile operator (if on 3G/4G). You can contact https://firebase.google.com/support/ with a device bugreport to help the team investigating this particular case.

Comment: @diego-giorgini I made a few more tests. Same app in a new device with a different carrier. Worked fine. Took Simcard from this device and put in my device. Guess what? Worked fine too... Indeed seems a Carrier / infrastructure issue. All tests made over LTE / 4G. Thanks!